# Chrome how to open popup in new window instead of new tab (20170629_chrome 59.0.3071.115)

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome

Editted: For my probelm, not sure but I think hat this update of Google Chrome do not support many options for some specific browsers. So when we has them in [specs param](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) of `window.open()`, it omits all the `height=h,width=w,left=x,top=y` which make chrome open link in new window instead of new tab

For my program, now I only keep this and this solve the problem:

```
window.open(form_url, form_name, "width=w,height=h,left=x,top=y");
//our problem code below
//window.open(form_url, form_name, "width=w,height=h,left=x,top=y,resizable=yes,location=yes,scrollbars=yes");
```

//End editted =================

Could someone help me in configuring Chrome so that popup will open in new window, instead of new tab? (Or any programmatically method for asp.net, c#)

It begin from today 2017/06/29, maybe newest update from chrome version 59.0.3071.115, and all popup in chrome would be opened in new tab instead of new window. This change our website behavior (our website use a main menu and others popup forms), and is very unexpected.

(Tested in some others site with ads popup, same behavior).

(Tested in Firefox: open popup in new window ok for all those sites, not new tab).

I have read changelog here but no mention about this change: [chrome 59.0.3071.115](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/59.0.3071.109..59.0.3071.115?pretty=fuller&n=10000)

I have searched google, too, but got no luck, maybe because of my google skill, maybe because this is new change from Chrome so google can't find question about it?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3):

On programmatically open new window and not new tab, you can do it via JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(fncOpenNewWindow);

function fncOpenNewWindow() {
        $('#testURL').unbind();
        $('#testURL').on('click', function () {
            window.open("", 'Window Name', "height=200,width=200,modal=yes,alwaysRaised=yes");
        });
    }
</script>
```

This is the control:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")" id="testURL">Click Me</a>
```

This is tested on Chrome. I haven't tested this on other browser but this should work fine with Chrome.

Comment: Glad to help @PhamX.Bach :)

Comment: I did some experimenting and found that resetting window.open(...)'s "location" and "toolbar" parameters to "0" (or "no") made my popups open in a new window again. Removing the two parameters entirely also works as a fix.

Answer (score 2):

I have the problem too. I fixed by change `toolbar=no` or remove `toolbar` feature.

```
 window.open('http://google.com','x', 'height=600,width=600,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no')
```

Comment: Removing "toolbar" alone might not be enough. I also had to remove the "location" parameter to get the popup to open in a new window. (I formerly had both of these set to "1")

Comment: Thank you, I think that this update of Google Chrome do not support many options for some specific browser so when we has them in option param of window.open(), it omits all the `height=h,width=w,left=x,top=y` which make chrome open link in new window instead of new tab.

Comment: @jball037 OK, I just remove toolbar, and it is work for me. (Chrome: 59.0.3071.115) You can try in http://jsfiddle.net/mrjuju/jcmk4jf9/1/